Function $\frac{x}{1+x}g(a-x) + \frac{1}{1+x}g(-x)$ has a unique maximizer over $x\ge0$, for any concave increasing function $g$ and $a>0$
Let $g:(-L,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly concave, increasing, and differentiable function with $L > 0$ such that $g(x)\to -\infty$ as $x \to -L$. Also, let the map $f$ be defined on $[0,L)$ as $$ f(x) =  (x/(1+x))g(a-x) + (1/(1+x))g(-x),$$ where $a > 0$ is fixed. Observe that $f(x)$ is a convex combination of $g$ evaluated at two distinct points. I am trying to show that this map admits a unique (global) maximizer over its domain, or to find a counterexample. I have a counterexample to show that $f$ is in general not concave. I believe that $f$ is quasi-concave, but have not been able to prove it. Edit: I am also interested in the case where $g$ is defined on the whole real line in which case $f$ is defined on the non-negative reals.

Doesn't $g(x)=-x^2$ and $a=10$ give you a counter example?

Don't think so, this function is unbounded thus admits no maximizers.

Oh I misunderstood the notion of maximizer. You mean a global one, I was thinking about local ones.

Won't this always blow up for $x\to -1$? Because in order for it not to blow up, we needed $g(1)=g(a+1)=0$, but $a>0$ and $g$ must be strictly concave and increasing. But such a function cannot exists, because that would mean, that $g$ is $0$ between $[1, a+1]$ and hence $\nabla g=0$ on $(1, a+1)$, which contradicts the fact that strictly concave functions are strictly bounded by their 1st order Taylor polynomials.

Note that the domain of $f$ is the non-negative reals. I am looking for a maximizer on the set $[0,\infty)$.

Do you want to show $f(x)$ has a unique global maximizer over $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$?

Yes, exactly.  Since $f(x) \to - \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and $f(0) = g(0)$, the function $f$ admits at least one global maximizer, but I want to show that it is unique.

Could you give an example of $g$ and $a$ for which the maximizer of $f$ is greater than $0$?

@Amir Sure, take $g(x) = 10 log(x+1)$ and take $a = 5$.

But $\log(-x+1)$ and  $\log(5-x+1)$ are not well defined for all $x\in [0,\infty).$

@Amir Ok then take $g(x) = 1-e^{-0.5x}$. In the other case, I would be interested in showing the existence of a unique global maximizer on compact set where $f$ is well defined. In the previous example, this would be the set $[0,1]$.

For your first example, the set is $[0,1)$.

@Amir Yes you are right.

The function $f$ is quasi-concave on $[0,L)$ considering that all of its $\alpha$-supersets $\{x \in [0,L): f(x)\ge \alpha \} $ are convex sets (hint: the product of $x$ and a decreasing concave function is concave). Hence, $f$ is unimodal, i.e., either decreasing or increasing-first-decreasing-next (it cannot be increasing as it goes to $-\infty$ as $x \to L$). As $g$ is strictly concave, $f$ cannot be constant on any interval. Therefore, $f$ has a unique maximizer on $[0,L)$.

PS: It can be shown that for $a\le 1$, the maximum is attained at $0$ and for $a> 1$ the maximizer is in the interval $[0,a-1]$. Update: This follows from that for $a<x+1$ the derivative of $f$ can be bounded as follows:
$$ f'(x) =  -g'(a-x)+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\left(g(a-x)-g(-x) \right) +\frac{1}{x+1}\left(g'(a-x)-g'(-x) \right) \\ \le -g'(a-x)+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}a\,g'(-x)+\frac{1}{x+1}\left(g'(a-x)-g'(-x) \right)\\ \le -g'(a-x)+\frac{1}{x+1}\,g'(-x)+\frac{1}{x+1}\left(g'(a-x)-g(-x) \right)=g'(a-x)\left(1-\frac{1}{x+1} \right)<0.$$

Agreed: Factoring, one finds ${1+x}^{-1}$ multiplied by a strict concave function,  and the quasi-concavity of this product just follows by definition. Can you elaborate on why the PS holds?

@jmsac sure I will add more details as I spare some time. I derived it by showing that the derivative of $f$ is negative for $x+1> a$.

In your comment: $(1+x)^{-1}$; you may edit it.

@jmsac You may check the update elaborating on why the PS holds.

Alternative solution (inspired by @Amir's nice answer)
We have
$$f(x) = \frac{h(x)}{1 + x}$$
where $h(x) := xg(a-x) + g(-x)$.
As @Amir pointed out, $h(x)$ is concave. Indeed, we have
$h''(x) = -2g'(a-x) + x g''(a-x) + g''(-x) < 0$.
We have
$$f'(x) = \frac{(1+x)h'(x) - h(x)}{(1+x)^2}.$$
Let $F(x) := (1+x)h'(x) - h(x)$.
We have $F'(x) = (1 + x)h''(x) < 0$.
Thus, $F(x)$ is strictly decreasing.
Thus, $F(x) = 0$ has at most one real solution.
Thus, $f'(x) = 0$ has at most one real solution.
Thus, $f(x)$ has a unique global maximizer (easy).
